# :before and :after on Firefox with CSS 3D not rendering in order

Tags: css, firefox, transform

I am using CSS to display some spinning coins as shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gdrQ/1/

Some of the relevant code is as below:

```
.coin {
    background-image: url("http://coins.thefuntimesguide.com/images/blogs/presidential-dollar-coin-reverse-statue-of-liberty-public-domain.png");
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    [...]
}

.coin:before {
    background-image: url("https://www.intnumis.com.au/images/product_gub257zcoy_201310GoldProofHoleyDollarDumpREV_medium.jpg");
-moz-transform: translateZ(-5px);
    [...]
}
```

and I rotate with:

```
-moz-transform: rotateY(1080deg)
```

Opera, Safari and Chrome are working just fine, but Firefox always shows the coin:before image  on top when the coin is not spinning.  When it is spinning everything works fine, but maybe 1s after the animation stops, it seems the div re-renders and for any rotated coins instead of seeing the before image, the back of the other image is shown.

I'd be grateful for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question instead of deleting it incase anyone has a similar problem.

I need to add a perspective unit, for example like this:

```
body {
    perspective: 800px;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
}
```

And it works fine in Firefox as well.

Updated fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/6gdrQ/3/